# Modal - Can't make a condition work with a prop

Tags: javascript, next.js

Im trying to make a Modal and when someone clicks to open it I want to disable scrollbar.

My Modal is a component and I cant pass the prop "open" to the condition. When someone clicks to open the Modal the condition doesn't work and the scrollball stays.

My Dialog.js is where I have my array and my functions, I pass them as props to the others components, to each individual Modal.

Dialog.js

```
export default function Dialog() {
  let [Dentisteria, setDentisteria] = useState(false);
  let [Endodontia, setEndodontia] = useState(false);
  let [Ortodontia, setOrtodontia] = useState(false);

  const dataEspecialidades = [
    {
      setOpen: setDentisteria,
      open: Dentisteria,
    },
    {
  
      setOpen: setEndodontia,
      open: Endodontia,   
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      setOpen: setOrtodontia,
      open: Ortodontia,
    },
  ];

  return (
    <>
          <div className="grid gap-8 mx-auto md:grid-cols-3">
            {dataEspecialidades.map((item) => {
              return (
                <>
                  <Card setOpen={item.setOpen}>
                    <CardTitle>{item.title}</CardTitle>
                    <CardDescription>{item.text}</CardDescription>
                  </Card>

                  <Modal setOpen={item.setOpen} open={item.open}>
                    <ModalTitle>{item.title}</ModalTitle>
                    <ModalDescription>
{item}
                    </ModalDescription>
                  </Modal>
                </>
              );
            })}
          </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

My Card component is used to open the Modal and its working. I pass the prop
`setOpen` that I have in my Dialog.js.

Card.js

```
export function Card({ setOpen, children }) {
  return (
    <>
      <div
        onClick={() => setOpen(true)}
        className="px-4 py-6 text-center rounded-lg cursor-pointer select-none bg-gradient-to-br from-white to-neutral-50 drop-shadow-lg"
      >
        {children}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

My Modal component is used to show and close the Modal and its working. I pass the prop `setOpen` and `open` that I have in my Dialog.js.

But the `open` prop is not working in the condition to hide the scrollbar when the Modal is open.

Modal.js

```
export function Modal({ open, setOpen, children }) {
  if (typeof document !== "undefined") {
    if (open) {
      document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
    } else {
      document.body.style.overflow = "";
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div
        className={`${open ? "" : "hidden"} fixed z-10 inset-0 overflow-y-auto`}
      >
        <div className="flex items-center justify-center min-h-screen p-4">
          <div className="fixed inset-0 bg-black opacity-30"></div>

          <div className="relative w-full max-w-2xl p-8 mx-auto bg-white rounded-lg">
            {children}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: What if you have two modals? one open, one not

Comment: I don't understand what are you saying.. my modal works just the condition to hide the scrollbar doesn't

Comment: What I'm asking is how do you resolve the situation when you have multiple modals and one does `document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";` and the next one does `document.body.style.overflow = "";` and the third one does ... and the fourth, fifth, ... ?  how do you handle this? These Modals obviously don't get created when the are shown and destroyed when they are not shown. They exist next to each other and are toggled `open=true` or `false`.

Comment: Because "open" is passed as a prop and "open" it's different for each Modal. I have an array of Modals and I set "open" and "setOpen" for each one. And the function thats opening each different Modal is working. Just the condition for the scrollbar I cant make it work

Comment: I updated my question with more information @Thomas, so you can help me better

Comment: Its not necessarily possible to open multiple modals and thats not the question anyway

Comment: @FroboZ But I dont want to open multiple Modals, the array is just for information, I open the Modals individually, just one at the time. I just cant make the codition to disable the scrollbar work.

Comment: @Sanntozzz I know, I was trying to make this point to the commenters on your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not tracking open with a state, you could use the useEffect hook for this
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

```
  const [modalIsOpen, setmodalIsOpen] = useState(open);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Update the body style when the modalIsOpenState changes
    if (modalIsOpen) {
      document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
    } else {
      document.body.style.overflow = "";
    }
  }, [modalIsOpen]); // adding this will run useEffect any time modalIsOpen changes see the "Tip: Optimizing Performance by Skipping Effects" part of the documentation for more details
```

I realise your question is for next.js. I'm used to using React myself, you can use my answer in your Next.js application by importing useEffect like this

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
```